# Is there an idiomatic ruby/rails way of returning the first truthy mapped value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, functional-programming

I have an array of objects, some of which respond to :description, and I want to get the description from the first one with a truthy description.  I could do this:

```
objects.detect{|o| o.try(:description)}.description
```

or this:

```
objects.map{|o| o.try(:description)}.detect{|o| o}
```

but the first isn't DRY (description is in there twice) and the second iterates through the whole array before finding the value.  Is there anything in the ruby standard library, or in Rails' extensions to it, which would let me do something like this:

```
objects.detect_and_return{|o| o.try(:description)}
```

I know I could write it easily enough, but the standard libraries are big enough that I might not need to.  Is there a function which works like my `detect_and_return`?

Comment: Is there a functional programming term for this (apart from lazy evaluation)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't seen such a method, and the closest I found was a method `capture_first` which I found in the gem `merb-cache`. Seems they stumbled on the same problem and implemented this:

```
module Enumerable
  def capture_first
    each do |o|
      return yield(o) || next
    end
    nil
  end
end
```

You could also take a look at the [Array](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Array.html) and [Enumerable](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html) methods in the Ruby [facets](http://rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/master/file/README.rdoc) library and see if you find something similar. Facets contains quite a lot of goodies, so you might get lucky.

Comment: Indeed - Enumerable#find_yield, aka Enumerable#map_detect.  Thanks - I'd not heard about facets before.

Comment: I'm always surprised (and disappointed and increasingly resigned) when something like this isn't already part of core Ruby: `find` and `select` and `reject` with no block are completely useless identity functions, so it's beyond me why none of them supply the obvious default block of `{|e|e}`.

Comment: You can, by the way, do `select(&:itself)` rather than the slightly uglier `select {|i| i}`